# Valgrind - Suppression file too general?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, suppress-warnings, suppression

I'm new to *valgrind* and the first thing to notice was, that the standard C-Library on OS X El Capitan seems to leak memory (*possibly lost*). After a little bit more reading this isn't the case and it is possible to exclude the system-lib from the *valgrind leak summary* with a suppression file.

I generated one such suppression file (by running a simplistic program) and adding the errors to the suppression file. It looks like this:

**osx_el_capitan_c_lib.supp**

```
{
  <osx_el_capitan_c_lib>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: possible
   fun:malloc_zone_malloc
   fun:_objc_copyClassNamesForImage
   fun:_ZL9protocolsv
   fun:_Z9readClassP10objc_classbb
   fun:gc_init
   fun:_ZL33objc_initializeClassPair_internalP10objc_classPKcS0_S0_
   fun:layout_string_create
   fun:_ZL12realizeClassP10objc_class
   fun:_ZL22copySwiftV1MangledNamePKcb
   fun:_ZL22copySwiftV1MangledNamePKcb
   fun:_ZL22copySwiftV1MangledNamePKcb
   fun:_ZL22copySwiftV1MangledNamePKcb
}
```

Now I have a few questions:

- Is it possible that this file will suppress leaks of my actual code (not system-libs)? I tested a little bit with definitely leaking/not leaking code and it seems to work fine. But how can I be sure?
- A default output current looks like this (definitely not leaking):

  ```
      ==37004== Memcheck, a memory error detector
      ==37004== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
      ==37004== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
      ==37004== Command: ./val.o
      ==37004== 
      ==37004== 
      ==37004== HEAP SUMMARY:
      ==37004==     in use at exit: 22,100 bytes in 187 blocks
      ==37004==   total heap usage: 271 allocs, 84 frees, 28,340 bytes allocated
      ==37004== 
      ==37004== LEAK SUMMARY:
      ==37004==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      ==37004==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      ==37004==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      ==37004==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      ==37004==         suppressed: 22,100 bytes in 187 blocks
      ==37004== 
      ==37004== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
      ==37004== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 18 from 18)
  ```

  As you can see the suppression file works pretty good for now (no bytes shown as lost, etc.). But the heap summary doesn't get affected by the suppression file it seems (`allocs`/`mallocs` are shown - they happen outside my code) and the leak summary shows *suppressed* as it's own field. Is there a way I can disable this field (a flag or something) and to suppress the (`allocs`/`mallocs` outside my code) in the heap summary as well?

Comment: *how can you be sure*   this seems to be asking for an opinion. opinions are outside the scope of stackoverflow

Comment: @user3629249 This definitely isn't an opinion. I was hoping for an answer like *You can('t) be sure, since the suppression file explicitly links to the system library and excludes code written outside these libraries.*.